# How to separate concerns updating ObservedObject when new data comes in?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `PostManager` class which basically holds a list of Posts. I use this as the single-source-of-truth.

```
class PostManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [Post]()

    func updatePostMessage(postId: Int, message: String) {
        // here I call the api and receive a new Post object

        if let newPost = data.data?.post {
            self.updateMessage(for: newPost)
        }
    }

    func updateMessage(for newPost: Post) {
        if let postIndex = posts.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == newPost.id}) {
            posts[postIndex].message = newPost.message
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a function that I call which I use to call the API to update the `Post` message.

I also created a function `updateMessage` which finds the right `Post` given the `id` and update its message.

A `Post` looks like this:

```
struct Post: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var message: String
    var createdAt: String?
    var updatedAt: String?
    // many other properties...
   
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case title = "title"
        case message = "message"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}
```

My question is: I will be adding dozens of additional API calls to the `PostManager` class, along with dozens of additional functions to update specific properties of the `Post`, like `updateMessage`.

How can I keep the API call functions in `PostManager`, but move the `Post` update functions into another class, while keeping the `@Published var posts` updated?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do this? It seems to me that the API call functions and the `Post` update functions all accomplish the same goal (namely to keep the list of `Post`s up-to-date), so I don't feel like there are any concerns to be separated. Not saying the question is incorrect, but we may need more context.

Comment: @Cheezzhead It's a fair question. The reason why I ask is because this class will likely have many many dozens of calls and update functions down the road, and I feel like separating the calls from the update functions will be more organized?

Comment: Will it be possible in your scenario to send the whole Post object in a PUT request and update the complete object. This means the old properties will be updated with same existing data and if there are new values they will overwrite the old values.

Comment: @azamsharp If I update the entire property, wouldn't the entire view be re-rendered? Instead of just the one view (like the Post message).

Comment: Only the views that are using the Post model properties will be re-rendered. Other views might get re-evaluated but re-evaluation is a very fast process and it should not effect performance in most scenarios.

Comment: Why do you even want to update only a single property of your post? How about just replace the whole post at the index?
`... posts[postIndex] = newPost ... `

Comment: What if the API fails? This seems like an inconsistency nightmare.

Comment: @azamsharp I use all other properties of the Post object in some of my views. My understanding was that if I update the entire object, the entire view would have to be re-rendered. Is that not right?

Comment: @LoVo I use all other properties of the Post object in some of my views. My understanding was that if I update the entire object, the entire view would have to be re-rendered. Is that not right?

Comment: Anytime you update anything in an ObservableObject the parent and the children views are rerendered. That is why Apple is phasing it out with Observable.

Comment: In addition to all other comments, it would be worth to consider to refine the API. It is entirely possible to have just _one_ update function which can mutate any of the properties of a post. Under the hood, your network may use the `PATCH` request which is very versatile and is a perfect fit for a complex use case. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATCH_(HTTP)

Answer (score 1):

I am referring to your question in the comment.

*TL;TR:*
There is no difference when you replace a single property of a post or the complete post.

SwiftUI provides DEBUG method which can show you which data causes your view to update. `Self._printChanges()`

So lets write a quick demo:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Post: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var message: String
}

@Observable class PostManager {
    var posts: [Post] = [Post(id: 1, title: "1", message: "1")]
        func updatePostMessage(postId: Int, message: String) {
            
        // Switch these methods to check the output of which view is re-rendered
        posts.updatePostMessage(with: Post(id: postId, title: "1", message: message))
        posts.updatePostTitle(with: Post(id: postId, title: "1", message: message))
            
//         posts.updateCompletePost(with: Post(id: postId, title: "1", message: message))

    }
}

// This code could go to a different file to answer your initial question
extension [Post] {
    mutating func updatePostMessage(with newPost: Post) {
        if let index = self.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == newPost.id }) {
            self[index].message = newPost.message
        }
    }
    
    mutating func updateCompletePost(with newPost: Post) {
        if let index = self.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == newPost.id }) {
            self[index] = newPost
        }
    }
    
    mutating func updatePostTitle(with newPost: Post) {
        if let index = self.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == newPost.id }) {
            self[index].title = newPost.title
        }
    }
}

struct TitleView: View {
    let title: String
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ =  Self._printChanges()
        Text(title)
    }
}

struct MessageView: View {
    let message: String
    var body: some View {
        let _ =  Self._printChanges()
        Text(message)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var postManager = PostManager()
    var body: some View {
        let _ =  Self._printChanges()

        VStack {
            ForEach(postManager.posts) { post in
                TitleView(title: post.title)
                MessageView(message: post.message)
            }
          
            Button {
                postManager.updatePostMessage(postId: 1, message: "Message")
            } label: {
                Text("Update")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We are going to ignore the initial log when the view gets rendered for the first time.

When we use the method which only changes the message of the post the console is:

```
ContentView: @dependencies changed.
MessageView: @self changed.
```

If you change the update method in the extension above and update the complete post the console is:

```
ContentView: @dependencies changed.
MessageView: @self changed.
```

And only if you explicitly set a different title it would update the TitleView.

```
ContentView: @dependencies changed.
TitleView: @self changed.
MessageView: @self changed.
```

Answer (score -1):

SwiftUI is smart enough to know which parts of the view need to be redrawn when observed data changes. So assigning an updated version of a `Post` object to the same index in the `posts` array, will only cause the views that depend on the changed data to be rerendered.

```
class PostManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [Post]()

    // ...
    
    func update(with newPost: Post) {
        if let postIndex = posts.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == newPost.id}) {
            posts[postIndex] = newPost
        }
    }
}
```

If the `newPost` contains only an updated message, views that display that message will rerender. If `newPost` is an exact copy of the original post, nothing will be updated (at least nothing that will noticeably impact performance).

With this model, actually retrieving updated `Post` data can be done anywhere, as long as you pass the data back into the `update(with:)` method when it's received. It's hard to say how exactly without knowing too much about your project, but at least the api calls are now separated from your manager.

For example, using an dependency injection pattern would look something like this:

```
public protocol API: Sendable {
    // ...

    func updatePost(withId: Post.ID, data: Post) -> Post
}

class PostManager: ObservableObject {
    func update(with newPost: Post, on api: some API) {
        let updatedPost = api.updatePost(withId: newPost.id, data: newPost)
        if let postIndex = posts.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == newPost.id}) {
            posts[postIndex] = updatedPost
        }
    }
}
```

There is a bit of redundancy here because as it stands, the data to send over API for updates is of the same type as the data used in your views (both are just the `Post` struct). But as the scope of your project increases, you may want to separate those (by having, for example, a `Post.Model` struct that is `Codable`, freeing the `Post` struct of that restriction).

Comment: An ObservableObject does a complete invalidation of the parent and the children. No matter what you change SwiftUI is connected to 1 objectWillChange that redraws everything.